# Battery Charging and discharging in Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

In the [model attached](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/318520-battery-charging-and-discharging) there are two batteries. First battery is charging the second battery. There is a breaker which is used to break the circuit and stop the charging after 5 seconds. The problem is, second battery continue charging ever after the breaker is open. Please suggest how is it possible. And how to overcome this problem. I want to stop the charging after 5 seconds of simulation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the doc for [Breaker](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/breaker.html),

```
Note: The Breaker block may not be the appropriate switching device to
use for DC circuits. For such applications, it is recommended that you
use the Ideal Switch block as a switching device.
```

If you change your model to use the [Ideal Switch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/idealswitch.html) then you'll see the circuit breaking at the 5s mark as you expect.